# Does redundant code get managed in the compiler or does it get executed everytime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I was working on optimizing an old code (and transferring some to a newer project) and I stumbled upon this code

```
if (typeList.FirstOrDefault()?.typeId == Constants.OpenTextTypeId)
    generatedTextStrBuilder.Append("Empty");
else if (typeList.FirstOrDefault()?.typeId == Constants.OutSideId)
    generatedTextStrBuilder.Append($" [{ typeList.First().typeName }] ");
else if (Constants.typeListOfReview.Contains(typeList.FirstOrDefault()?.typeId))
    generatedTextStrBuilder.Append($"*[{ typeList.FirstOrDefault()?.typeName }]*");
else
    generatedTextStrBuilder.Append($"_[{ typeList.FirstOrDefault()?.typeName }]_");
```

as you can see in the code 
`typeList.FirstOrDefault()?.typeId` is written in each condition once

**The question is:** does the compiler manages this type of redundancy or does it execute it everytime?

And if the compiler does, does it only manage it inside this method?

Comment: The compiler doesn't execute your code, that's the job of the CLR.

Comment: Indeed. The compiler transforms your code into IL code, which is then run by the CLR. In that regard, each use of `FirstOrDefault` will result in a separate set of IL instructions, so yes, the same code will effectively be run repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect the compiler to cache the result - FirstOrDefault is deterministic, unless the underlying list changes between checking the conditions to the branches, but that is certainly not something the compiler knows about. You could have just as easily called an extension method on IEnumerable that returned a random every time item instead of the first one. You can easily validate this by creating your own extension method, something along these lines...

```cs
public static class MyEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static T MyFirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing FirstOrDefault()");
            return enumerable.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }



public class Program
{


    public class Type
    {
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var typeList = new List<Type>
        {
            new Type { TypeId = 4 }
        };

        if (typeList.MyFirstOrDefault().TypeId == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        }
        else if (typeList.MyFirstOrDefault().TypeId == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
        else if (typeList.MyFirstOrDefault().TypeId == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("other");
        }
    }
}
```

Console output is

```
Executing FirstOrDefault()
Executing FirstOrDefault()
Executing FirstOrDefault()
other
```

I would certainly extract the expression that returns the typeId into a variable - it's better for readability as well.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has to emit code that calls `FirstOrDefault()` every time. After all any of the following could be true:

- The object refered to by `typeList` might change between the `if` and the `else if`, e.g. in a multithreaded application.
- The output of `FirstOrDefault` could depend on some external state, not just on the input, so multiple calls could return different things.
- `FirstOrDefault` could have side effects.

If you think about it, the only way the compiler could remove the "redundant" code is if

- `typeList` is an immutable collection of immutable objects which returns the items in the same order every time
- `FirstOrDefault` is a pure function, i.e. it only depends on the input and has no side effects, and
- `typeId` returns the same value if the underlying object didn't change.

(This list of conditions is most likely not complete, and it might be far more tricky than this simple list might suggest)

Answer (score 0):

Yea. it will be executed every time BECAUSE

When i built a small project (RELEASE build) for example

```
int i = 0;
Console.WriteL("Hello world !")
```

and compiled it and generate exe file

Then i **de-complied** it by **.Net Reflection** and i saw that redundant line (`int i = 0`) still exists in complied code.

Comment: This experiment does not prove the premise of the question. First of all, the question is about a function call, not about a local, unused variable. Second, your line of code _will_ be removed entirely with the appropriate optimizations enabled, because it can be deduced by the compiler not to have any effect.

Comment: Neither am I. My point is that what you did, does not prove that your answer answers the OP's question.

Comment: @CodeCaster i respect to u .i am agree with you and accept your idea.yea that might not prove the concept of the question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1804-remove-unused-locals?view=vs-2019': _"The C# compiler removes unused local variables when the `optimize` option is enabled."_